# Undefined reference to "cv::optflow::createOptFlow_DualTVL1()"

Tags: opencv, go

I have successfully installed `gocv` package from https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv and I am trying to run C++ code which I wrapped in C library inside my Go project. But there seems to be the problem when I try to call `cv::optflow::createOptFlow_DualTVL1()` method. I get undefined reference error. I dont know why, since in `optflow.hpp` file there is a method called `createOptFlow_DualTVL1()`

Here is my `main.go` file:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_optflow
#include "dense_flow.h"
*/
import (
       "C"
       "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main(){

}
```

**NOTE:** `dense_flow.h` is where I have declared my `CalculateT4VL1()` function which calls to `createOptFlow_DualTVL1()` inside `dense_flow.cpp` file.

Operating System and version: Ubuntu 18.04

OpenCV version used: 4.0.0

GoCV version used: 0.18

Go version: 1.12

Answer (score 1):

This optical flow imported from contrib module.
You need advanced import ( https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/tree/master/contrib ):  "gocv.io/x/gocv/contrib"

Comment: Actually algorithm I am trying to use is not part of that module. That is why I am wrapping C++ code in C which I am trying to use in Go.

Comment: Undefined reference error says then linker needs a object with implementation: *.o or *.obj, *.a or *.lib. Implementation of this function is here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/6389627d8a9377c0bac0441b69493e52210079fd/modules/optflow/src/tvl1flow.cpp . And do you need link opencv_optflow library.

Comment: Well if I have everything in my /usr/local/include directory I do not understand how it cannot find it? Since I ran a test program which uses opencv_video and it works. Not sure whats going on now.